# Railsのajaxで正しいcreate.js.erbの書き方が分からない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery

表題の通り、railsでajax通信を実装しようとしているのですが、create.js.erbの書き方で躓いています。

create.js.erbは以下の様になっています。

```
$("#likebutton").html("<%= button_to post_like_path(@post.id,@like.id), method: :delete, remote: true do  %>いいねを消す<% end %>");
```

上のコードの.html()の中身を単に.html("いいねを消す")にしたところ正常に動いたので、原因は

.html("<%= button_to post_like_path(@post.id,@like.id), method: :delete, remote: true do  %>いいねを消す<% end %>")

の書き方にあると思うのですが、正しい書き方が分かりません。

また、createメソッド内で、@postと@likeをきちんと定義できています。

よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<%= ... %>` は do と end を分けるといったことができません。
だいぶ無念な感じですが次のようにすると一応動きます。

```
$("#likebutton")
  .html('<%= button_to "https://www.google.com", method: :delete, remote: true do
                 "消します"
             end %>');
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
そもそも、do endの形で分けることができないんですね。

これを機に代替案を探ってみようと思います。
今回は、本当にありがとうございました。